# API инвентаризация в "МойСклад"

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Добавил вебхук на обновление списка инвентаризации. В /entity/webhooks сам вебхук вижу.  Но на сервер ничего не приходит (все логи пустые). Остальные вебхуки работают. Можно как нибудь проверить что срабатывает данный вебхук?

Answer (score 0):

Веб-хуки МоегоСклада срабатывают на создание, обновление, удаление конкретных документов. Если Вы создали веб-хук с `"action": "UPDATE"`, то он придет, когда будет обновлена любая инвентаризация. Если `"action": "CREATE"`, то веб-хук придет при создании новой инвентаризации.

Проверить работу веб-хуков можно по [статье](https://moysklad.github.io/workbook/api/remap/1.1/ru/webhooks.html#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82).

Comment: Вы можете проверить и сказать точно что вебхуки для инвентаризации работают на стороне моего склада?

Comment: Действительно, сейчас недоступны вебхуки для Инвентаризаций. Задачу внесли в планы

Comment: И когда все это дело заработает?